# Cannot pull attributes from another model in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

Here is a customer model that I want to populate with attributes from address.js model, however, when we use Postman to post JSON, I get 500 Validation Error with not much hint as to the cause of the issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to sails,js, Javascript, and programming, so my syntax maybe wrong!

```
//Customer.js

var Customer = {
    attributes: {
        honorific: 'STRING',
        first_name: 'STRING',
        middle_name: 'STRING',
        last_name: 'STRING',
        addr:'Address.address',
        delivery_addr:'Address.address',

        fullName:function() {
            return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
        }
    }
};

module.exports = Customer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell Sails to pull in data from another model the way you are trying to. In essence, you are telling Sails that the `addr` and `delivery_addr` attributes are of type `Address.address` which doesn't make sense, because there is no such type in Sails.

What you need to do is use one of the Lifecycle Callbacks to pull in data from the address model. From your code and explanation I cannot exactly understand if the address is common for each Customer or, more likely, different for each Customer. If the latter is the case, I cannot really understand why you would want to pull in the address from another model to the Customer model. Perhaps if you explained a bit more what it is you are trying to achieve and why, I might be able to give you a better answer.

In any case, here's how you would use the `beforeValidation` lifecycle callback to pull in data from another model (untested).

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    honorific: 'STRING',
    first_name: 'STRING',
    middle_name: 'STRING',
    last_name: 'STRING',
    addr: 'json',
    delivery_addr: 'json',
    fullName:function() {
      return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
    }
  },

  beforeValidation: function(values, cb) {
    Address.findOne(1).done(err, address) {
      if(err) return cb(err);
      values.addr = address.toJSON();
      values.delivery_addr = address.toJSON();
      cb();
    });
  }

};
```